# como proibir acesso direto ao arquivo index.php e index.php/

Tags: php, htaccess, url

Olá, estou fazendo uso da `url` amigável, que está funcionando muito bem, porem quero proibir o acesso ao arquivo `index.php` e `index.php/`, quero que ao acessar eles seja redirecionado para a pagina `home.php`
Como faço isto?
Tenho que alterar algo no `.htaccess`?
porque da forma que coloquei aqui abaixo pra TENTAR resolver o problema não funciona, veja:

```
$pag = ($_GET['pag']));
if ($pag == 'index.php' || $pag =='index.php/')
{
   header("location: home");
}
```

O código acima funciona direitinho pra qualquer outra pagina, login,criar-conta, etc, menos quando se trata do index, parece que não é PERMITIDO.

Alguém sabe o que fazer?

Comment: não seria `location:home.php` ao invés de `location:home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a Array `$_SERVER[]`

```
<?php
$URL= "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
if ($URL === "/index.php" || "/index.php/") {
    header("location: home.php");
}
?>
```

Mas talvez só o `header("location: home.php");` mesmo, resolva.

E com uma pesquisada na internet achei isso pro .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://siteDaMiriam/home.php
```

Não sei se dá certo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar no final do seu  index.php e index.php/ o seguinte:

```
<?php
header('location:home.php');
?>
```

Com isso toda vez que alguém entrar nessa pagina, vai ser processado tudo que tive nela e depois vc será redirecionado para a pagina que foi inserida dentro do `header`.